# Initializing and storing a matplotlib gridspec layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I would like to create a class that represents a data visualization dashboard. The dashboard has a certain predefined layout, and I am trying to define it with `matplotlib.gridspec`.

The layout is fixed for each instance of the dashboard, but should be filled with different plots. How can I best initialize and store the layout, and only later fill it with plots?

The  `initLayout` method already outputs a plot, I don't want that.

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyDashboard:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def initLayout(self):
        gs = gridspec.GridSpec(120, 100)
        layoutAx = {}
        layoutAx["InfoArea"] = plt.subplot(gs[0:10, :])
        layoutAx["OverviewArea"] = plt.subplot(gs[10:20, :])
        layoutAx["TimelineArea"] = plt.subplot(gs[20:40, :])
        layoutAx["PerformanceArea1"] = plt.subplot(gs[40:80, :])
        layoutAx["PerformanceArea2"] = plt.subplot(gs[80:120, :])
```

Comment: Using your example and running `MyDashboard().initLayout()` does not output a plot for me.

Comment: Maybe it does so only because I run it from a Juptyer notebook with `%matplotlib inline´?

Comment: Yes, without %matplotlib inline it doesn not output anything. Anyway, is this the right way to initialize and store the layout?

Comment: That is it, i guess. Jupyter automatically shows a figure even if you do not call `plt.show()` at the end of a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure why it would be undesired to already create the plot, if the goal at the end is to actually create a plot, you may of course separate the definition of the gridspec from the axes creation.

A suggestion:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyDashboard:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def initLayout(self):
        gs = gridspec.GridSpec(120, 100)
        layoutAx = {}
        layoutAx["InfoArea"] = gs[0:10, :]
        layoutAx["OverviewArea"] = gs[10:20, :]
        layoutAx["TimelineArea"] = gs[20:40, :]
        layoutAx["PerformanceArea1"] = gs[40:80, :]
        layoutAx["PerformanceArea2"] = gs[80:120, :]
        self.layout = layoutAx

    def applyLayout(self):
        self.axesdic = {}
        for name, layoutspec in self.layout.iteritems():
            self.axesdic.update({name : plt.subplot(layoutspec)})
```